# Cursor for loop - substr(char) to date, subtracting sysdate - PLSQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr, to-date, sysdate

Maybe someone can help me..
I have the cursor for loop here. I want to print out the first name and the age (in decimals, ex. 55,6 years). I know that the WHERE part of my code is not correct.
I'm trying to take the first 6 char(year and month) with substr() function from a varchar2(12) string. Then I want to change it to a date and subtract from the sysdate. Maybe I'm wrong. Feeling confused :(

```
CREATE TABLE client(
pers_nr VARCHAR2(12) PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR2(20);

INSERT INTO client VALUES('19490321-789','Anna');


declare 
cursor c_info_client is select fname, substr(pers_nr, 1, 6)
                        from client
           --wrong!--   where substr(pnr, 1, 6) : = to_date(YYYY-MM) - sysdate;
begin
for rec in c_info_client loop
dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.fname) ||', ' || rec.pers_pnr ||' years');
end loop;
end;
```

The answer should look like (one of many rows):

Anna, 34,7 years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to want a `where` clause at all; you want to convert the first six characters of the `pers_nr` to a date, and see how many years are between that and today.

You can calculate the age with:

```
trunc(months_between(sysdate, to_date(substr(pers_nr, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM'))/12, 1)
```

- `substr(pers_nr, 1, 6)` gives you the six characters => 19490321
- `to_date(substr(pers_nr, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM')` turns that into a date => 1949-03-21
- `months_between(sysdate, ...)` gives you the number of months => 839.4
- `months_between(sysdate, ...)/12` gives you the number of years=> 72.196
- `trunc(..., 1)` truncates that to one decimal place => 72.1

So your PL/SQL block would be:

```
declare 
  cursor c_info_client is
    select fname,
      trunc(months_between(sysdate, to_date(substr(pers_nr, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM'))/12, 1) as age
    from client;
begin
  for rec in c_info_client loop
    dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.fname) ||', ' || rec.age ||' years');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

which gives:

```
Anna, 72.1 years
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b8be86248f237e3e9c3d1bfdf85ef40a) with a cursor, and a plain query to show the steps.

You could use `trunc(sysdate)` to take the time from midnight this morning, but it won't make much difference here.

By default the age will be shown with the decimal separator from your session NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting. If you want all users to always see the same separate than you can use `to_char()` with a suitable format mask.

Comment: You don't have an idea how much I appreciate your answer (and the explanations)! Thank you so much! :)